# Dimension of the space of Katz modular forms divisible by $\phi(N)$

Tags: modular-forms

Let $N\geq 3$ be an integer. Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic 0. Is the dimension of the $K$-space of holomorphic Katz modular forms of level $\Gamma(N)$ and weight $k$ divisible by $\phi(N)$ for any positive integer $k$?

$\phi(\cdot)$ is Euler's totient function.

I think this should be true because the modular curve should have $\phi(N)$ geometric connected components that are all isomorphic to each other. On the other hand, this conclusion is a little bit confusing for me since it means that Katz modular forms over $\mathbb{C}$ are not the same as classical modular forms but rather are the same as the direct sum of $\phi(N)$ copies of classical modular forms, right?

Comment: If you look at Diamond--Shurman section 3.9, you'll see that these components are taken into account in the dimension formula for level $\Gamma(N)$, so  they do agree. Unless I'm misunderstanding what you mean by "classical modular forms".

Comment: @LerayJenkins I mean functions on the quotient of the upper half-plane by $\Gamma(N)$ (which is connected, I think). I will look at the reference, thank you.